# How to convert an Integer Handle to HWND

Tags: c++, windows, handle, uicontrol

I am writing a small test program, and for that i require the handle of an edit control. I have copied the value of the handle from Spy ++ (lets say 000A0B40).

So i did the following

```
#define editControlHandle 0x000A0B40

int *intHandle;
intHandle=(int*)editControlHandle;
HWND handle=(HWND)intHandle;
int textlength=GetWindowTextLength(handle);
```

I also did a `getlasterror` and it gave me error_success.

Comment: Quite a lot of work to get a window handle. You can simply write `(HWND)0x000A0B40`

Answer (score 2):

GetWindowTextLength cannot retrieve the length of the text of an edit control in another application.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)